# problems with android geofencing

Tags: android, android-geofence

I'm creating this geofencing app using the google sample tutorials. All works well except for this part which keeps showing an error:

In the SimpleGeofence.java, I have:

```
  public class SimpleGeofence{
...
public Geofence toGeofence() {
        // Build a new Geofence object
        return    new Geofence.Builder()
                       .setRequestId(getId())
                       .setTransitionTypes(mTransitionType)
                       .setCircularRegion(
                               getLatitude(),
                               getLongitude(),
                               getRadius())
                       .setExpirationDuration(mExpirationDuration)
                       .build();
    }
```

The error shows under the **Geofence.Builder()**, and I'm being asked to create a class 'Builder' in type 'Geofence'.

When I create the class under Geofence.java, the error moves to **.setRequestId(getId())** and I'm asked to create a method '**setRequestId(String)**' in the type 'Builder'. This is what i have in the **Geofence.java** after creating all these;

```
package com.kamerlabs.wocmantv;

public class Geofence {

    public class Builder {

        public Object setRequestId(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

An error now shows on **.setTransitionTypes(mTransitionType)** and I'm asked to **'Add cast to method receiver'**. This is where i need help..what should i do now. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove generated Geofence class and continue to work with the class from    `com.google.android.gms.location` package. Import it into your SimpleGeofence.java as following.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
```

As the next make sure your `getId()` method, used in `.setRequestId(getId())`, returns a String.